# Is there a way to view the progress of a RAID 5 rebuild on a G Technology G-Speed Q?

Tags: raid, raid5

I've got a G Technology G-Speed Q configured in RAID 5 fitted with 4x 2TB 7200RPM drives. The top drive started flashing amber and the red light at the bottom also started flashing. I got a new 2TB 7200RPM drive fitted it, started up the drive and found that it no longer showed up via Firewire 800, nor USB2.0. The replaced drive bay was still flashing amber and red light at the bottom still flashed and I left it for 24 hours to rebuild the array.

After 24 hours the array had not rebuilt itself and the drive in question's amber light was still flashing and the red light at the bottom still flashing.

I replaced the previous drive and was able to access data on the drive again then followed the directions as per the used manual below and hot swapped the drive in question while the unit was powered on as per the steps form the manual below:

> Follow the steps below to identify and replace a failed drive.
>
> 1. With the unit powered up, locate the malfunctioning drive by visually inspecting the drive modules. If an amber LED is lit for a
>    drive, that drive has failed.
> 2. Remove the failed drive by inserting the provided key into the lock hole, and gently sliding the drive module out of the enclo- sure. Be
>    careful about which drive you pull out. REMOVING THE WRONG DRIVE WILL
>    RESULT IN THE LOSS OF THE ARRAY AND ALL OF ITS CONTENT.
> 3. Replace the failed drive with a new disk module. Secure it in place by pushing in the drive and latching the handle.
> 4. If G-SPEED Q was setup in RAID 5 mode, the unit will begin rebuilding data on the drive. During this process, all drive LEDs will
>    indicate data access. The rebuild time is approximately 2 hours per
>    TB.
> 5. Once the rebuild is complete, G-SPEED Q is back to normal and protecting your valu- able data once again.

I've given the drive another 8x hours to rebuild and still no change -- I can access the files on the drive but it's very slow (as one would expect during a rebuild).

The configurator utility (when attached via USB2.0) does not find the drive but strangely all the drive bay lights return to their normal blue colour while the red warning light at the bottom still flashes red. Killing the program and we're back to the affected drive bay flashing amber with the new drive in it like before.

Is there some other software I could try that might give me more insight into what's happening with this drive so see if it is actually trying to rebuild the array and how far it is?

Comment: With the age of this thing, probably other drives are failing as well. I hope you have a backup.

Comment: I use this device as one of many backups so I'm not looking for way to retrieve data. I'll probably try reconfiguring the unit from scratch and start again -- but I would like to get the RAID 5 rebuild working if at all possible.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the (small) [reference manual](http://support.g-technology.com/sites/default/files/g_speed_q_user_guide_0.pdf), the red led means a failure of the G-SPEED Q unit itself. From the manual:

> If the red warning light is lit, there is a failure of one of the
> internal components. Stop using G-SPEED Q and contact our Technical
> Support.

I must admit that is strange to have a chassis failure at the same time a drive failed. I  think that the failed drive caused the chassis "to panic", and *maybe* a physical reboot (off/on cycle) can help. If that fails, you can only try a RAID reconfiguration (via the proper tool) **but at the cost of losing all data stored in it.**

So I would follow the manual's advice - if the unit is under warranty, call the tech support.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm going to give it another 24 hours to rebuild. Red light at the bottom seems normal as per this thread (https://creativecow.net/forums/thread/g-speed-q-failed-led-alarm/). If it does not come right, I'll attempt to reconfigure from scratch. This is one of many backup drives so no need to worry about recovering data. It's old and out of support. Will keep you posted. Also possible that my replacement disk is bad but unlikely. Just would have been nice to be able to see the rebuild progress.